# Show the manufacturer with the 2nd top sales in the year of 2009 and the manufacturer with the 2nd top sales in the year of 2010

Tags: sql-server

I have data in 6 six tables and I have joined 3 tables. I want to return an output in two different columns.

This is what I am doing but going wrong.

```
SELECT  
    (SELECT 
    TOP 2 Manufacturer_name
    FROM Fact_Transactions FT
    LEFT JOIN DIM_Model DM ON FT.IDModel = DM.IDModel
    LEFT JOIN DIM_MANUFACTURER MFC  ON MFC.IDManufacturer = DM.IDManufacturer
    Where DATEPART(Year,date)='2009' 
    group by Manufacturer_name 
    Order by SUM (TotalPrice) ) as A,


        (SELECT 
    Top 2 Manufacturer_name
    FROM Fact_Transactions FT
    LEFT JOIN DIM_Model DM ON FT.IDModel = DM.IDModel
    LEFT JOIN DIM_MANUFACTURER MFC  ON MFC.IDManufacturer = DM.IDManufacturer
    Where DATEPART(Year,date)='2010' 
    group by Manufacturer_name
    Order by SUM (TotalPrice)) as B
```

/*This is showing error => Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression. */

```
CREATE TABLE DIM_MANUFACTURER (
IDManufacturer INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(11, 1),
Manufacturer_Name VARCHAR (20)
)

CREATE TABLE DIM_MODEL (
IDModel INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(101, 1),
Model_Name VARCHAR(20),
Unit_price MONEY ,
IDManufacturer INT REFERENCES DIM_Manufacturer(IDManufacturer)
)
CREATE TABLE FACT_TRANSACTIONS (
IDModel INT REFERENCES DIM_MODEL(IDModel),
IDCustomer INT REFERENCES DIM_CUSTOMER(IDCustomer),
IDLocation INT REFERENCES DIM_LOCATION(IDLocation),
Date DATE REFERENCES DIM_DATE([DATE]),
TotalPrice MONEY,
Quantity INT,
)

INSERT INTO DIM_Manufacturer VALUES 
('Apple'), ('Samsung'), ('One Plus'), ('Nokia'), ('Motorola'), ('HTC')

INSERT INTO DIM_MODEL VALUES
('iPhone 4', 377, '11'), 
('iPhone 4S', 414, '11'), 
('iPhone 5', 456, '11'), 
('iPhone 6', 501, '11'), 
('iPhone 7', 552, '11'), 
('Thunderbolt', 201, '16'), 
('C139', 121, '15'), ......



INSERT INTO FACT_TRANSACTIONS VALUES
(130, 10044, 2001, '05/25/2009', 500, 1), 
(107, 10043, 2001, '04/16/2003', 126, 1), 
(126, 10022, 2005, '11/03/2003', 169, 1), 
(111, 10045, 2003, '01/01/2010', 286, 1), 
(118, 10012, 2010, '04/21/2007', 149, 1), 
(128, 10044, 2005, '10/19/2010', 318, 1), 
(124, 10003, 2009, '10/03/2010', 435, 1), 
(117, 10002, 2003, '10/13/2010', 54, 1), .....
```

Comment: Please provide sample data with sample output for all tables you are using.

Comment: Please edit the question Sir...Don't comment it.

Comment: Okay sir. let me do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case I think DENSE_RANK() and CTE will be very useful. Here a solution:

```
WITH cte AS
(
SELECT Manufacturer_name, DATEPART(Year,date) as yr,
DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY DATEPART(Year,date) ORDER BY SUM(TotalPrice) DESC) AS Rank 
    FROM Fact_Transactions FT
    LEFT JOIN DIM_Model DM ON FT.IDModel = DM.IDModel
    LEFT JOIN DIM_MANUFACTURER MFC  ON MFC.IDManufacturer = DM.IDManufacturer
    group by Manufacturer_name,DATEPART(Year,date) 
),
cte2 AS(
SELECT Manufacturer_Name, yr
FROM cte WHERE rank = 2
AND yr IN ('2009','2010')
)
SELECT c.Manufacturer_Name AS Manufacturer_Name_2009
,t.Manufacturer_Name AS Manufacturer_Name_2010
FROM cte2 AS c, cte2 AS t
WHERE c.yr < t.yr;
```

Comment: Sir showing some error:  Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS'.  Case must be followed by END ?

Comment: Sir Thanks for the solution.. it is working now but not showing values; only headers as Manufacturer_NAME_2009 Manufacturer_NAME_2010    but no values.. where am I going wrong?

Comment: Problem is with data i suppose. Since you are creating some columns as identity and using them as foreign keys where you are providing some different values have a look for column IDModel between table Fact_Manufacturer and DIM_Model. Provide the link if you can for the whole data so i can check if data is wrong or not.

Comment: Thanks sir. It is working now. Thanks a lot. Manufacturer_NAME_2009 Manufacturer_NAME_2010
Samsung  NULL
NULL Apple

Comment: Sure sir.. You solved my issues.  If i want to remove Null values from the output above ? what could be the way?     Samsung Apple to retain only these two values.   Also, can the problem be also solved using simple sub query?

Comment: I updated the solution, try now. I think some changes i have to do if there are more than 2 manufacturer on 2nd Top Position.

Comment: Sir, wonderful. This is exactly I wanted. But, it is getting complicated for me to grab. If possible could you please make as simple as possible using simple subqueries etc. ?

Comment: I updated my solution have a look now. I tried to create simple one but in your case I think complex query is the only solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `row_number()`

```
select X.Manufacturer_name as Manufacturer_name_09,Y.Manufacturer_name as Manufacturer_name_10
 from 
    (
            SELECT Manufacturer_name,row_number() over(order by SUM (TotalPrice)) as rn1
            FROM Fact_Transactions FT
            LEFT JOIN DIM_Model DM ON FT.IDModel = DM.IDModel
            LEFT JOIN DIM_MANUFACTURER MFC  ON MFC.IDManufacturer = DM.IDManufacturer
            Where DATEPART(Year,date)=2009
            group by Manufacturer_name 

    )X inner join
    (

        SELECT Manufacturer_name,row_number() over(order by SUM (TotalPrice)) as rn2
            FROM Fact_Transactions FT
            LEFT JOIN DIM_Model DM ON FT.IDModel = DM.IDModel
            LEFT JOIN DIM_MANUFACTURER MFC  ON MFC.IDManufacturer = DM.IDManufacturer
            Where DATEPART(Year,date)=2010 
            group by Manufacturer_name 

    )Y on X.rn1=Y.rn2  and rn1 in (1,2) and rn2 in (1,2)
```

Comment: Sir, it showing ... Incorrect syntax near ')'... I tried different ways but couldn't do it. Is it possible to do it without CASE WHEN as well?

Comment: Sir.. showing a few errors... Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 168
Incorrect syntax near '2009'.
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 177
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Order'.
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 189
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Order'.    What is the simplest way to solve this? Subqueries can be applied?

Answer (score 0):

**use this...**

```
SELECT  top 1 * 
 from
    (SELECT 
    TOP 2 Manufacturer_name,
    SUM(Quantity )  TQ1
    FROM Fact_Transactions T1
    LEFT JOIN DIM_Model D1 ON T1.IDModel = D1.IDModel
    LEFT JOIN DIM_MANUFACTURER D2  ON D2.IDManufacturer = D1.IDManufacturer
    Where DATEPART(Year,date)='2009' 
    group by Manufacturer_name, Quantity 
    Order by  SUM(Quantity ) DESC ) as A,


        (SELECT 
    Top 2 Manufacturer_name,
     SUM(Quantity ) TQ2
    FROM Fact_Transactions T2
    LEFT JOIN DIM_Model DM ON T2.IDModel = DM.IDModel
    LEFT JOIN DIM_MANUFACTURER DM2  ON DM2.IDManufacturer = DM.IDManufacturer
    Where DATEPART(Year,date)='2010' 
    group by Manufacturer_name,Quantity
    Order by  SUM(Quantity )DESC ) as B
```

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH RANK1 AS 
    (
        SELECT MANUFACTURER_NAME,YEAR(DATE) AS YEAR,
        DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY YEAR(DATE) ORDER BY SUM(TOTALPRICE)DESC) AS RANK
        FROM FACT_TRANSACTIONS AS T1
        INNER JOIN DIM_MODEL AS T2
        ON T1.IDMODEL = T2.IDModel
        INNER JOIN DIM_MANUFACTURER AS T3
        ON T3.IDManufacturer = T2.IDManufacturer
        GROUP BY Manufacturer_Name, YEAR(DATE)
    )
    SELECT YEAR, MANUFACTURER_NAME
    FROM RANK1
    WHERE YEAR IN ('2009','2010') AND RANK='2'
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.